# Python: Importing values from every second column of excel file into single python string, values separated by space

Tags: string, python-3.5, python-import, import-from-excel

How can I import the values from every second column sequentially into one string

> data

?
With screenshot of excel attached, I should get the string as follows:

data = ‘AASDH ABCA1 ABHD4 ABHD5 ABCD4 ACO2 ACOT7 ACP2 A2M ABCA1 ABCC4 ABHD4’

Comment: There are several popular Python libraries for reading Excel files.  Examine them, read the docs, try some things, and come back with specific questions if something goes wrong.

Comment: @DSM Is xlrd good way to go?

Comment: 'pd.read_excel("learn.xlsx", parse_cols=1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37)'

SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: `import pandas as pd`

`data = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", parse_cols="A,C,E,G, I, K, M, O, Q, S, U, W, Y, AA, AC, AE, AG, AI, AK, AM, AO, AQ, AS, AU, AW, AY, BA, BC, BE, BG, BI, BK, BM, BO, BQ, BS, BU, BW, BY,  CA, CC, CE, CG, CI, CK, CM, CO, CQ, CS, CU, CW, CY")`

`data = data.to_string() `